# Почему qApp.quit() требует двух вызовов из QDialog?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qdialog

Имеется код, содержащий главное и диалоговое окна. Диалоговое запускается сразу же после главного, так как в него нужно передать координаты главного.

В диалоговом окне есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую выполняется `qApp.quit()`, однако, почему-то для выхода требуется нажать на кнопку 2 раза. Двойной вызов `qApp.quit()` тоже ничего не дает

Как сделать так, чтобы выход происходил только при одном нажатии? Из-за чего это происходит?

**Код:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
 
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(610, 371)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")

class Ui_Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, x, y, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(x + 20, y + 50, 400, 213))
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 361, 171))
        self.setWindowTitle("Dialog")
        self.pushButton.setText("ВЫЙТИ")
 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClick)
 
    def onClick(self):
        app.quit()
 
 
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

dlg = Ui_Dialog(MainWindow.x(), MainWindow.y())
dlg.exec()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: вы хотите при нажатии на кнопку `ВЫЙТИ` закрыть диалоговое окно, а главное окно остается открытым - так?

Comment: Для закрытия диалогового я бы использовал `self.accept()`. Мне нужно полностью завершить PyQt-программу из QDialog, но при этом не завершая весь скрипт целиком. То есть `sys.exit()` не подойдет

Comment: `sys.exit(app.exec_())` — В таком случае он произойдет _как только_ `app.exec_()` вернет значение...

Comment: Почему значение возвращается только при втором нажатии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используете сигналы для уведомления о любых изменениях или действие.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

 
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(610, 371)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")


class Ui_Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    myClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()                                   # <---
        
    def __init__(self, x, y, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(x + 20, y + 50, 400, 213))
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 361, 171))
        self.setWindowTitle("Dialog")
        self.pushButton.setText("ВЫЙТИ")

        # при нажатии pushButton, хотим, закрыть MainWindow
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myClicked)                # <---
        
        # при нажатии pushButton, хотим, выйти из диалогового окна
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)                   # <---


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

        dlg = Ui_Dialog(self.x(), self.y())
        dlg.myClicked.connect(self.onClick)                            # <---
        dlg.exec() 
        print('Диалог закрыт')

    def onClick(self):
        print('!!! onClick')
        # Закроем MainWindow, через мгновение, чтобы первым закрылся Ui_Dialog
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.close)                        # <--- !!!     


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]